# Variable is not a CFString when storing NSString in a NSDIctionary

Tags: ios, xmppframework

Im storing messages from my chat app in a NSDictionary. But, if i do

```
NSString *msg = [[message elementForName:@"body"] stringValue];
[m setObject:msg forKey:@"msg"];
```

It complains saying (when debugging) "Variable is not a CFString" and msg turns to nil. So, i changed it to:

```
CFStringRef cfstring=(__bridge CFStringRef) msg;
[m setObject:(__bridge NSString*) cfstring forKey:@"msg"];
```

but "msg" is still nil, and it shouldn't be nil.

This only happens when it sends messages. When its receives them... there is no problem!

Any help?

Comment: What does `elementForName:` return?

Comment: The body of the message received.

Comment: But is it a string? What happens when the body is empty? etc..

Comment: Yes, it's a string. When it tries to add a null value to a dictionary, it crashes.

Comment: I check that the value of the string sent is >1 before sending.

Comment: Why are you calling `stringValue` on a string then?

Comment: I copy/pasted that code, worked, and let it be.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12694/discussion-between-david-ronnqvist-and-fustigador)

Answer (score 0):

Should you not be using `objectForKey` rather than `elementForName`? It the object is an `NSString` when it's stored you shouldn't need to use `stringValue`. You definitely shouldn't need to worry about toll-free bridging to a CFStringRef, this is just the underlying C data type the compiler is seeing